# Relación de tablas SQL server

Tags: sql-server, modelorelacional

yo se que la pregunta puede que no este acorde con las que uno hacer normalmente, pero, tengo 3 tablas con relación M,N,1 y me piden que para relacionarlas exporte las PK de las tablas con M y N en una nueva tabla, pero no se como hacer eso de *EXPORTAR* las PK. Le dejo una imagen para que miren lo que estoy haciendo según lo que entiendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es necesario que indiques como se relacionan, a través de que campo se relacionan cada tabla, por favor intenta explicar un poco más o es imposible que te ayudemos. Además indica si es inserción en una nueva tabla o es en una tabla virtual... Gracias :)

Comment: la tablas nuevo es una tabla virtual, creo, solo la uso para relacionar las tablas, al momento de relacionar factura con la nueva tabla me sale un error. "comoBoth sides of a relationship must have the same number of columns".

Comment: La nueva tabla parece tener todas las claves al reves?

Comment: como asi? al reves?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo quieres hacer por el diagrama de base de datos:

1. Arrastra desde la tabla de relación hacia la primaria, en este caso desde `proclientefac` hacia `factura`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Elige todos los campos que deben ir en la relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]